# ConstraintLayout half of a view inside and another outside

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want my textview at bottom of another view, but half inside, and half outside with constraint layout.

image:

[image]

tried Baseline, but only align on middle

Comment: What did you tried so far ? show us.

Comment: Did you try in your application?

Comment: Does the green view have fixed size or not?

Comment: i tried like the Anmol said, tried Baseline too.. but not worked

Comment: hiddeneyes02 nop, 0dp and default height is wrap(wrap_content for constraintlayout)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/another_view"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/another_view"
```

Set these properties for the textview. Here the `another_view` is the id of the view over which the textview is to be placed.
What it does it it aligns the textview's top and the textview's bottom to the bottom of the view.

Comment: This not work, tested... this not go over the another_view

Comment: yeah, i make 0dp and height_default wrap, but only wrap_content worked like a charm, thanks

Comment: Yes it should work :) Great that it solved your problem